# Pass variable to view through render() function

Tags: laravel

So I want to pass variable to view using `render()` function like this:

```
final class Partners extends Component
{
    public $partners;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->partners = Partner::all();
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('partners');
    }
}
```

But it says variable is undefined. So I am wondering is it possible to pass variable to view like this? Or maybe I need to register this class somewhere?

Comment: If the answer worked for you, mark as "the answer" to close your question.

Answer (score 3):

You're not sending any variable with the view. change it to this

```
    public function render()
    {
        return view('partners', ['partners' => $this->partners]);
    }
```